# Dart - Get total amount in a list

Tags: dart

Given this list

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Bread",
        "sellingPrice": 10

    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Drink",
        "sellingPrice": 30,

    }
]
```

and class

```
class Food {
  String id;
  String name;
  double sellingPrice;
}
```

What i want here is to get the total amount . Just like below code but in dart.

```
foodlist.sum(c=>c.sellingprice)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fold` method on your `List` or use `map` combined with `reduce`:

```
class Food {
  String id;
  String name;
  double sellingPrice;
}

void main() {
  List<Food> foodList = [Food()..sellingPrice = 5, Food()..sellingPrice = 10];

  print(foodList.fold<double>(0.0, (sum, food) => sum + food.sellingPrice)); // 15
  print(foodList.map((food) => food.sellingPrice).reduce((a,b) => a + b)); // 15
}
```